# Need to run a custom command during Windows 7 Setup between Phase 3 and 5

Tags: windows-7, unattended, dism

How can I run a cmd script during windows setup somewhere between the beginning of phase 3 and the beginning of phase 5?  I need to copy hardware dependent files from the USB drive to the C: drive before the hardware detection kicks in.  I use wmic, which runs in WinPE, to determine the hardware.

Posted [here](https://superuser.com/q/974533/213596) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone deleted the linked question, but it was answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/974808/need-to-run-a-custom-command-during-windows-7-setup-between-phase-3-and-5) after I reposted :(